# Download multiple zip file

Tags: php

I want download multiple zip for multiple image at a time.But my code crate only one zip file for all image.

```
    foreach ($data as $key => $files) {
    /*$fileName="file.zip";*/
    $fileName = $key.'.zip';
    $tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', '');
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($tmpFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // download file
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);

        $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $fileContent);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
    readfile($tmpFile);
    echo $fileName;
    unlink($tmpFile);
}
```

Comment: It is easy to put multiple images in multiple files, but, as far as I know, you can only download one file "at a time".

Comment: Please guide me what should I do for this, Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to download multiple file if you initiate _multiple forced downloads with Javascript_. There are many ways to do this, an example can be found here: [Force Download with JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-download). Just use the `downloadFile()` routine multiple times. Do not use this on unsuspecting users because it is probably not what they expect.

Comment: I create multiple directory in single zip and it's better for me. Thanks